# ExactTarget: ExecuteFilter Function in sendable content?

Tags: email, marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to run an AMPScript that is calling a previously created data extension filter, and while it works in landing pages, when I try to send an email with this script it errors out.  The send preview says:

```
ExecuteFilter Function is not valid in content. This function is only allowed in non sendable content.
```

Any ideas about how I can fix this?  Is it possible to run a filter in an email AMPScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is telling you that the function you are running is not allowed in sending.  It would only be available in landing pages.

You would send the email to the resulting filtered data extension.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Thank you, though.

Comment: Some functions are restricted to lp's due to scalability.  If you do some functions in a large email send, it will kill servers due to processing.  They just aren't meant to scale.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.